# Add class name in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am using CakePHP to build my application. And I want to add a class name of `btn btn-primary btn-sm` to an `<a>`

My code for the element is as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
    'Add to cart',
     array('action' => 'add', $inventory['Inventory']['id']),
     array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?'),
     array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'));
?>
```

This results in the created code as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm(&quot;Are you sure?&quot;)) { document.post_5250d38671023789772963.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Add to cart</a>
```

I have tried placing the class array as the first array, the middle array, and the last array all of which had the own set of problems. The way it sets currently, the class name does not get observed as you can see from the code above.

What do I need to do to fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [postLink](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3apostLink) doc in cookbook
It explains postLink as

```
FormHelper::postLink(string $title, 
                     mixed $url = null, 
                     array $options = array (), 
                     string $confirmMessage = false)
```

So modified version on your code can be written as

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink('Add to cart',
                                  array('action' => 'add', $inventory['Inventory']['id']),
                                  array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'),
                                 'Are you sure?');
?>
```